# Memory leak error with dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-leaks

While compiling an with GCC, the sanitizer is pointing to a memory leak error:

```
Direct leak of 10707 byte(s) in 347 object(s) allocated from:
#0 0xffff7f87432c in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../gcc-11.2.0/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:145
#1 0x417208 in dup_line (/opt/ncl/ni/src/nyacc/nyacc+0x417208)
#2 0x41bca4 in copy_action (/opt/ncl/ni/src/nyacc/nyacc+0x41bca4)
...
```

in the following subroutine

```
char *
dup_line()
{
    register char *p, *s, *t;

    if (line == 0) return (0);
    s = line;
    while (*s != '\n') ++s;
    p = MALLOC(s - line + 1);
    if (p == 0) no_space();

    s = line;
    t = p;
    while ((*t++ = *s++) != '\n') continue;
    return (p);
}

void
copy_action()
{
    register int c;
    register int i, n;
    int depth;
    int quote;
    char *tag;
    register FILE *f = action_file;
    int a_lineno = lineno;
    char *a_line = dup_line();
...
}
```

Is the subroutine dup_line missing anything or is there something else wrong with it? Thanks.

Comment: It's telling you that memory that was allocated in `dup_line` was never passed to `free`.  You need to do that at some point later in your code when the memory is no longer is use.

Comment: It's not my code, I'm just trying to fix it. How would I accomplish your suggestion?

Comment: Figure out when the memory is no longer in use, then pass the pointer to `free` at that time.

Comment: Am I supposed to do this in every subroutine that calls `dup_line` because I don't see how I could do it globally? For example, in `copy_action`, would I just include `free (a_line)` at the end of this subroutine?

Comment: If the memory is no longer in use, then yes free it then.  If it's still in use when `copy_action` returns, then do it at a later time.

Comment: I'm freeing it at the end of the `copy_action` subroutine.

Comment: @afernandezody, Since `copy_action()` does not return anything and does not have any out parameters, that is probably the right thing to do.  Beware, however: if it assigns a pointer (in)to the allocated memory to a file-scope variable then you would probably better off living with the memory leak, as it would be much more difficult to determine when the allocated memory is no longer needed.

Comment: After `char *a_line = dup_line();`, `a` does **not** point to a _string_ as the data lacks a _null character_.  I suspect subsequent use of `a` leads to UB.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Isn't `dup_line()` supposed to assign a string to `a_line`?

Comment: Do not fix it as I have never seen worse code in my life. Everything in global variables, some strange macros like `MALLOC`. Write the program from the scratch.

Comment: I wish that were an option! I just need to find a way to suppress the memory leak (rewriting the code would be a task for the developer)

Comment: Where and what is `MALLOC`? It is very trusting to have a non-static function that assumes that '\0' occurs after '\n'.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica unless `MALLOC` was a macro invocing `calloc`?

Comment: I'm just debugging it piece-by-piece.